# Правильная иерархия классов

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Никак не получается придумать логически непротиворечивую модель классов. В общем случае имеются следующие виды документов:

- Документ, состоящий только из заголовочной части (**сlass DocumentHeader**).
- Документ, состоящий не только из заголовка, но еще и табличной части (**сlass DocumentDetail**).

Классы, представляющие данные документы, являются абстрактными. Т.е. от них необходимо наследовать потомков, реализующих конкретную функциональность:

- `сlass DocumentHeader {}`
- `class DocumentDetail : DocumentHeader {}`

Теперь представим, что у нас есть конкретные документы:

- Итоговая заявка на товар. Содержит консолидированную информацию о заказе (**class Order**).
- Детальная заявка на товар. Помимо итогов, содержит табличную часть с заказом (**class OrderDetail**).

Имеем противоречие:

Детальная заявка должна наследовать функционал, реализованный в итоговой заявке, т.е.

- `class OrderDetail : Order {}`

Детальная и итоговая заявки должны наследовать функционал абстрактных классов DocumentHeader и DocumentDetail. Т.е.

- `class Order : DocumentHeader {}`
- `class OrderDetail : DocumentDetail {}`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой подход использовать в данной ситуации?

Comment: DocumentHeader - это блок документа. Он если и участвует в наследовании, то в качестве дочернего класса DocumentBlock. Детальный документ состоит из двух блоков, DocumentHeader и DocumentTable. Но, вообще, обычно части документа не стоит описывать классами вообще.

Comment: Я привожу несколько теоретические примеры, но в конкретной ситуации DocumentHeader, в виде его реализации Order, существует в виде полностью самостоятельной сущности. OrderDetail расширяет функционал Order.

Comment: @nrw, вот и зря он существуети является родителем для сущности, которая с ним не связана. Заказ - это сущность, которая описывается документом, но документом не является.

Comment: Order, как и OrderDetail - оба документы в физическом смысле, т.е. на бумаге. Бумаге невозможно объяснить, что она не документ. :)

Comment: Я бы посоветовал диаграмму на UML написать.

Comment: @nrw а смысл в такой абстракции вообще есть? Я про DocumentHeader и DocumentDetail. Даже по смыслу названия Header есть Header, как он может быть самостоятельным отдельным документом?

Comment: @nrw, еще раз - заказ не является документом. Документ - это представление заказа.

Comment: @Etki да, с такой позицией - модель, представление - я согласен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

хм... Помидорами просьба не кидаться

Если взять 1С, то там дается такое определение: Документ предназначен для описания информации о свершенных хозяйственных операциях в жизни организации вообще. (Проведенный документ - реально факт свершился, не проведенный - не более чем черновик - можно и удалить.)

Из бизнес-логики Заказ - это документ (есть хозяйственная операция), отражающий намерение одной стороны купить товар (заказать услуги), а другая сторона имеет намерения продать товар (оказать услуги).

При проектировании класса я бы взял за основу один класс, который включает в себя заранее известные реквизиты документа (дата создания, дата документа, наименование, сотрудник - чтоб было с кого спрашивать), плюсом сразу бы реализовал табличную часть (сохранение, изменения, удаления), а также некий флаг на то, что есть ли табл часть или нет (кстати, их может быть несколько). При этом при создании конкретного объекта (документа) - указываем доп. реквизиты, и флаг - есть лит у нас табл. часть или нет, если присутствуем - конкретизируем ее реквизиты.

*P.S. 1С, конечно, не любят программисты других языков (сам испытываю некоторый дискомфорт при работе с ней) - но при обучении многое в голове разложилось по полкам, в книгах много полезного материала для проектирования серьезных систем (не сайтов визиток, даже не каталогов).*

Как-то так.

Comment: А не проще объект, представляющий модель "табличной части", не инициализировать, вместо того, чтобы еще и флаг хранить?

Comment: Эвоно какую я глупость сморозил. Инициализировать, конечно, но null.